# For filtering data in Django, build dynamic query for multiple columns

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset, django-filter

I have to filter data from model based on the run time values. I am getting 5 values via query string. My querystring is like below:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/personal/search/?month=&year=&account=&deliveryManagedFrom=&marketmName=
```

So, I want to include all or none of the values in the filter so that it displays the desired result. Below is the filter query which I am writing:

```
sum_tt_count = NetworkRelatedInformation.objects.filter(month=month, year=year, account_id=account, account__deliveryManagedFrom=deliveryManagedFrom, account__marketName=market).aggregate(Sum('tt_count'))
totalttcount = sum_tt_count['tt_count__sum']
```

It is working well in case, all the values have been provided.

In case, if any value is blank, it should not consider that value and display output as per other  filter criteria.

Pls suggest how to implement an OR filter with 5 data inputs. It is not necessary that all 5 data inputs have values . So the value can be None or the value in the querystring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter the request for non-empty values and then use dictionary expansion to do the query.

```
q =  {k:v for k, v in request.GET.items() if v}
sum_tt_count = NetworkRelatedInformation.objects.filter(**q).aggregate(Sum('tt_count'))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It is awesome and generic which can be used for any number of values in the querystring.

Comment: HI Daniel... Can you Pls look on my other question  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51202612/how-to-pass-currently-logged-in-user-to-filter-py-i-e-request-based-filtering-in/51204787?noredirect=1#comment89401845_51204787
I tried multiple ways using filter method, @ property and qs but nothing is working for me.. Pls see if you can support on this

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using [**Q object**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

```
from django.db.models import Q

NetworkRelatedInformation.objects.filter(Q(month__isnull=True) | Q(month=month), Q(year__isnull=True) | Q(year=year)).aggregate(Sum('tt_count'))
```

Answer (score 0):

For handling the None values i have to explicitly write the below code.

```
account = request.GET.get('account')
if account is '':
    account = None
month = request.GET.get('month')
if month is '':
    month = None
year = request.GET.get('year')
if year is '':
    year = None


sum_alarm_count = NetworkRelatedInformation.objects.filter(Q(month=month) | Q(year=year) | Q(account_id=account)) \
    .aggregate(Sum('alarm_count'))
totalalarmcount = sum_alarm_count['alarm_count__sum']
```